# Why does select() return an empty string?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, ttk

I'm building an extensible text editor with Python and Tkinter, and I decided to use the ttk.Notebook widget to support multiple files opened for editing at once. I'm inheriting from Notebook and (among other things) overriding its `select` function so that it always returns a tab index instead of a tab identifier. In theory, this would make the API more consistent. However, when I call the unmodified `select` on startup, it returns an empty string, which is passed to `index`, which doesn't like empty strings.

Here's the function in question:

```python
def select(self, tabid=None):
    if tabid is None:
        return self.index(super().select())
    return super().select(tabid)
```

I know it's not caused by a misuse of `super()`, since the bug also happens with this test code:

```python
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
root = tkinter.Tk()
foo = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(root)
bar = tkinter.Frame(foo)
foo.add(bar)
foo.pack(); bar.pack()
print(repr(foo.select())) # prints ''
```

I can't find a case anywhere in the documentation in which `select()` might return an empty string. What am I missing?

Comment: @furas That worked for the test case, but not the real code. How would packing affect this?

Comment: I think widget added to `ttk.Notebook` doesn't need `pack()/grid()/place()`. Probably `ttk.Notebook` has own layout management - tabs need something different than objects placed (side-by-side) on one "surface" like window or frame.

Comment: @bkul The notebook widget itself, `foo`, must be placed/packed/gridded within the root window, as you did.  Widgets added to a notebook are managed by Notebook's specific geometry manager, just as with characters, items, and widgets placed within Entry, Text, Tree, and Canvas.